# How to split values to create a data frame with extra rows in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame such as this:

```
a  b
1  3
2  2
3  0
4  1
5  0
```

Here I have 5 rows and want to split the data such that I have 10 rows, for example:

```
a   b 
1   1.5
2   1.5
3   1
4   1
5   0
6   0
7   0.5
8   0.5
9   0
10  0
```

I have about 450 data sets such as this that all vary in length and all vary in what length I need them to be, for example the first is 107 rows long, but I want to split the data so that it becomes 250 rows long, the second is 275 rows long and I want to split it to 333 rows.

Does anyone know a formula that will allow me to do this in R?

Comment: Doubling the number of rows seems straightforward (assuming that `a` is just an index column), but I'm not sure how you want to do a general increase -- maybe show the 5 row to 7 row case to give an idea of how this should be handled?

Comment: Yes a is just an index column. I guess the 5 to 7 rows would look something like this: 1 = 3; 2 = 4; 3 = 0; 4 = 1; 5 = 6 which turns into 1 = 2.14; 2 = 2; 3 = 2.86; 4 = 0; 5 = 0.71; 6 = 2; 7 = 4.29. Though I'm not sure those numbers would be exactly correct. Basically the rows in each dataframe add up to the same value, but these values are spread across 7 rows instead of the original 5 rows.

Comment: Maybe give some idea of the motivation?  The simplest fix would be just `df2 <- data.frame(a=1:333, b=sum(df$b)/333)` -- it would yield the same sum but be of the correct size, but I'm guessing you want something more interesting than that.

Comment: Basically I have a vegetation transect where each row represents a plant and each value in that row represents the number of fruits on that plant. The problem I have is that one plant is not distinct from the next, and different observers have estimated plants to be of different sizes. So I know how many plants should be in each row (333) and I know how many plants have been counted in the transect (275). So I want to spread out the values from 275 rows to 333 rows, but I am interested in where the fruits occur (eg there might be more at one end of the transect than the other)

Comment: So I do not just want to average the values across all rows but rather spread them out where they are but into 333 rows instead of 275....

Comment: see my answer below; I thought you might want something like this.  My answer assumes that the total number should be constant, and the spatial density should be the same.  Basically I resample at regular intervals from the cumulative count.

Answer (score 2):

```
data.frame(a=seq(nrow(df)*2), b=rep(df$b/2,each=2))
   a   b
1   1 1.5
2   2 1.5
3   3 1.0
4   4 1.0
5   5 0.0
6   6 0.0
7   7 0.5
8   8 0.5
9   9 0.0
10 10 0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for this, that is great. But any ideas when it is not as simple as dividing by two? i.e turning 275 rows into 333 rows?

Comment: As you know there is no way to expand 107 rows into 275; or 275 rows into 333 uniformly because you cannot multiply a data frame to the target without breaking it apart. You could take a partial data frame.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to create a new variable in your original dataframe:

df$b2 = df$b/2

then create a new dataframe and append the old one:

df2 <- df

df2 <- rbind(df2, df)

then you can get rid of your original b2 variable if you'd like

df2$b <- NULL

Comment: Thanks again for this - this also works when I need to double the number of rows, but any ideas when I want to turn 275 rows into 333 rows?

Comment: What would you like in those additional 58 rows?

Comment: I would like the same data that is in the 275 rows but spread out into 333 rows. Can you add pictures on here? Perhaps a diagram would be better at explaining what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

So I'll go out on a limb with a guess as to what you would need in order to do the irregular resizing but maintaining the character of the original solution.

If we treat the elements as the deltas in a step function, then we can use the `approx` function to linearly interpolate from the `cumsum`, and then use `diff` to recover the originals.

The code would look like

```
resize.interpolate <- function(data, new.length) {
    l <- length(data)
    diff(approx(0:l/l, c(0, cumsum(data)), 0:new.length/new.length)$y)
}
```

Some examples

```
> df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=c(3,2,0,1,0))
> resize.interpolate(df$b, 7)
[1] 2.1428571 1.7142857 1.1428571 0.0000000 0.5714286 0.4285714 0.0000000
> resize.interpolate(df$b, 10)
 [1] 1.5 1.5 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.5 0.5 0.0 0.0
```

To roll it together, you would do

```
df2 <- data.frame(a=1:7, b=resize.interpolate(df$b, 7))
```